# How to check which element is dropped in which drag zone in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a question generator with a drag and drop question and I have a problem to check which element is dropped in which drag zone?

I don't honestly know if it's possible with Javascript only or do I need another library because I'm using vanilla JS.

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<p>Drag the image into the rectangle:</p>
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<img id="drag1" src="http://localhost/source1.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">
```

Comment: Your example already works... the variable `drag` contains the id of the element that was dropped (drag1), and `ev.target` contains the zone that it was dropped into (div1).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `id` of the element you dragged and the id of the element you dragged into:

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();

  const data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");

  const element = document.getElementById(data);

  ev.target.appendChild(element);

  console.log(`${data} in ${ev.target.id}`);
}

const draggables = document.querySelectorAll(".dragitem");

draggables.forEach(draggable => {
  draggable.addEventListener("dragstart", drag);
});

const div1 = document.querySelector("#div1");

const div2 = document.querySelector("#div2");

[div1, div2].forEach(div => {
  div.addEventListener("dragover", allowDrop);

  div.addEventListener("drop", drop);
});
```

```css
#div1,
#div2 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<p>Drag the image into the rectangle:</p>
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<img class="dragitem" id="drag1" src="http://localhost/source1.png" draggable="true">
<img class="dragitem" id="drag2" src="http://localhost/source1.png" draggable="true">
<img class="dragitem" id="drag3" src="http://localhost/source1.png" draggable="true">
<img class="dragitem" id="drag4" src="http://localhost/source1.png" draggable="true">
<img class="dragitem" id="drag5" src="http://localhost/source1.png" draggable="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve what you require would be to store the `id` of the dragged element in the `dataTransfer` store of the drag event. Then you can use this `id` to retrieve the element from the DOM when the `drop` event occurs, something like this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.draggable-entity').forEach(el => el.addEventListener('dragstart', drag));
document.querySelector('#div1').addEventListener('drop', drop);
document.querySelector('#div1').addEventListener('dragover', allowDrop);

function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("draggedElementId", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var draggedElementId = ev.dataTransfer.getData("draggedElementId");
  var draggedElement = document.querySelector('#' + draggedElementId);
  ev.target.appendChild(draggedElement);

  console.log(draggedElement.id);
}
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

img.draggable-entity {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<small>Drag the image into the rectangle:</small>
<div id="div1"></div>
<br />
<img id="drag1" class="draggable-entity" src="http://localhost/source1.png" draggable="true" title="1" />
<img id="drag2" class="draggable-entity" src="http://localhost/source1.png" draggable="true" title="2" />
<img id="drag3" class="draggable-entity" src="http://localhost/source1.png" draggable="true" title="3" />
<img id="drag4" class="draggable-entity" src="http://localhost/source1.png" draggable="true" title="4" />
<img id="drag5" class="draggable-entity" src="http://localhost/source1.png" draggable="true" title="5" />
```